# Can I set the Google Calendar Event Button - Privacy?

Tags: google-calendar-api

Is it possible to have a Google Calendar event button default to private when clicking the calendar button.

example:

[MyButton](https://www.google.com/calendar/render?action=TEMPLATE&text=Your%20Upcoming%20Appointment&dates=20130314T080000/20130314T090000&details=Reason%3a%20Your%20Upcoming%20Appointment%0A%0ATest%20Email%0A123%20Drive%20City,%20STATE%2036606%0A%0AWeb%20Site%3a%20%0A%0ADefault%0APhone%3a%20%28555%29555-9252%0AEmail%3a%20noreply@email.com&location=123%20Drive%20Test,%20State%20123456&trp=true&sprop=website%3a&sprop=name%3aTest%20Email&sf=true&output=xml)

defaults to the calendar default

I know the calendar API supports this but that would require me to create a custom landing page instead of directly hitting the Google calendar page and will push out my project timeline.

Thanks.